# htaccess mod_rewrite subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a mobile url that i want to redirect to subdomain m.

i.e. example.com/mobile  to m.example.com

However, when I have the url example.com/mobile/boston_resources/

it redirects to m.example.com/mobile/boston_resources/?city=boston
(instead of m.example.com/mobile/boston_resources/)

I'm using:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  page=[1-9]+        [NC,OR]
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a trailing `?` to your match to drop any *query string* present.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1?
```

Secondly, a `RewriteCond` does not apply to a `RedirectMatch` but a `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  page=\d+ [NC]
RedirectRule ^mobile/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

`[OR]` was dropped because there's only one `RewriteCond` and `[1-9]+` was changed to include `10` etc. Please note that putting a `RewriteCond` says that only redirect when you have `page=` in the query string. If you need the redirection regardless of that, drop the condition and just keep the rule.

Comment: Further to this I have noticed that example.com/mobile/boston_resources/  redirects properly without the www using my script

Comment: @martyn, (1) You forgot to tell which approach gave you the internal error. (2) Could you tell why do you check for `page=` when the URL that needs redirection doesn't have them? (3) Are you having multiple `.htaccess` files like in sub-dirs too? (4) Any guesses on what could add `?city=boston` because that seems application specific.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  page=\d+ [NC]
RedirectRule 301 ^mobile/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1? [R=301,L] gave the error. There are page numbers that need to be redirected too, although I can live without it. BTW I cannot reverse a css cache. On different browsers it still shows internal error, I have reverted to correct htaccess,cleared cache and used different devices. Do I have to restart apache to clear these.

Comment: @martyn, my bad! Please, drop the 301 from the rule. I forgot to remove it when I copied your redirect match. The redirection code is already specified by R=301 at the end of the rule. Can you test and let me know? Please, also read my update at the end of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @martyn, I'll certainly need more info than "didn't work" to help you out. Did you still get the internal error? You also didn't reply if you've checked for multiple .htaccess files. Cache has nothing to do here.

Comment: Yes the same internal error as before. My own methods work but I have the issue stated

Comment: @martyn, Thanks for accepting. But, I guess you're still half-way there. If you update your question with "source url", "redirected url" and your "expected url." I'll be happy to take another shot at it.

Comment: redirected url http://www.example.com/mobile/london_flats/ expected url http://m.example.com/london_flats/  source url /mobile/mobile-flats.php?city=$1  also  redir: http://www.example.com/mobile/estate_agencies/(.*), expected url http://m.example.com/agencies/(.*)  source url /mobile/mobile-agencies.php?uname=$1

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1?
```

Seems to do the trick. I have sacrificed the need for the pages to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache or use a different browser to test it.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=.+ [NC]
RedirectRule ^mobile/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1? [R=302,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.